# How to pass multiple arguments from a dynamic checkbox into a pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, pipe

I have multiple filters in a pipe in order to filter out smartphones by characteristics. Currently, it works only for one checkbox per category, but I'd like to be able to include multiple filters per category (Ex. Search for both samsung and Apple brands) This checkbox is dynamically generated, based on an API call, so I'd like for the pipe to accept an indeterminate number of arguments. Thanks in advance!

I have attempted to do a for loop within the pipe, and apply an array of strings as an argument.

filter-component.html

```
<mat-drawer-container style="overflow-y: hidden;" class="example-container">
  <mat-drawer mode="side" opened>
    <div class="wrapper" #wrapper>
      <div class="sidebar" [ngStyle]="{'margin-left': marginSize, 'position': sideNavPosition, 'z-index':20, 'height':open===true? collapsedHeight : '100%'}">
        <ul class="list-sidebar bg-defoult">
          <li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".filtermenu" class="collapsed active">
              <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i>
              <span class="nav-label">Filter</span>
              <span class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></span>
            </a>

            <ul class="sub-menu collapse filtermenu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#brandlabel" id="dashboard">
              <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#brand" class="collapsed active" id="brandlabel">
                <span class="nav-label">Brand</span>
                <span class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="nav-label collapse" id="brand" *ngFor="let Product of brand; let i = index">
                <li class="nav-label text-light">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="f{{i}}" value="f{{i}}" (change)="setSearchBrand(Product)" /> {{Product}}
                </li>
              </ul>

            </ul>
            <ul class="sub-menu collapse filtermenu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#batterylabel" id="dashboard">
              <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#battery" class="collapsed active" id="batterylabel">
                <span class="nav-label">Battery</span>
                <span class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="nav-label collapse" id="battery" *ngFor="let Product of battery">
                <li class="nav-label text-light">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="{{Product}}"  (change)="setSearchBattery(Product)" /> {{Product}}
                </li>
              </ul>

            </ul>
            <ul class="sub-menu collapse filtermenu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cameralabel" id="dashboard">
              <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#camera" class="collapsed active" id="cameralabel">
                <span class="nav-label">Camera (MP)</span>
                <span class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="nav-label collapse" id="camera" *ngFor="let Product of camera">
                <li class="nav-label text-light">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="{{Product}}"  (change)="setSearchCamera(Product)" /> {{Product}}
                </li>
              </ul>

            </ul>
            <ul class="sub-menu collapse filtermenu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#colorlabel" id="dashboard">
              <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#color" class="collapsed active" id="colorlabel">
                <span class="nav-label">Color</span>
                <span class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="nav-label collapse" id="color" *ngFor="let Product of color">
                <li class="nav-label text-light">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="{{Product}}"  (change)="setSearchColor(Product)" /> {{Product}}
                </li>
              </ul>

            </ul>
            <ul class="sub-menu collapse filtermenu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ramlabel" id="dashboard">
              <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ram" class="collapsed active" id="ramlabel">
                <span class="nav-label">RAM</span>
                <span class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="nav-label collapse" id="ram" *ngFor="let Product of ram">
                <li class="nav-label text-light">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="{{Product}}" (change)="setSearchRam(Product)" /> {{Product}}
                </li>
              </ul>

            </ul>
            <ul class="sub-menu collapse filtermenu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#resolutionlabel" id="dashboard">
              <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#resolution" class="collapsed active" id="resolutionlabel">
                <span class="nav-label">Screen Resolution</span>
                <span class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="nav-label collapse" id="resolution" *ngFor="let Product of resolution">
                <li class="nav-label text-light">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="{{Product}}"  (change)="setSearchResolution(Product)"
                  /> {{Product}}
                </li>
              </ul>

            </ul>
            <ul class="sub-menu collapse filtermenu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#storagelabel" id="dashboard">
              <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#storage" class="collapsed active" id="storagelabel">
                <span class="nav-label">Storage</span>
                <span class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="nav-label collapse" id="storage" *ngFor="let Product of storage">
                <li class="nav-label text-light">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="{{Product}}" (change)="setSearchStorage(Product)" /> {{Product}}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </ul>
            <ul class="sub-menu collapse filtermenu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#filterlabel" id="dashboard">
              <a (click)="clearFilters()" class="collapsed active" id="filterlabel">
                <span class="nav-label">Clear Filters</span>
              </a>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li (click)="viewProducts()">
            <a>
              <i class="fa fa-gamepad"></i>
              <span class="nav-label">Products</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>
              <i class="fa fa-gamepad"></i>
              <span class="nav-label">FAQ</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="sidenavbtn" [ngStyle]="{'left':open === true ? '37vh' : '0px', 'z-index':19}">
        <button (click)="toggleNav()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
          <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-drawer>
  <mat-drawer-content>
    <!--this is used to fetch the products-->
    <div class="container-fluid main-body ">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 navbar-fixed-top" *ngFor="let product of products | brandFilter : searchBrand:searchBattery:searchCamera:searchColor:
                    searchRam:searchResolution:searchStorage">
          <figure class="card card-product">

            <div class="img-wrap text-center">
              <mdb-carousel class="text-center d-flex justify-content-center" [interval]="'0'">
                <mdb-carousel-item *ngFor="let image of product.images">
                  <div class="img-wrap text-center ">
                    <img class="text-center" src="{{'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+image.image}}" style="width:200px;height:200px;">
                  </div>
                </mdb-carousel-item>
              </mdb-carousel>
            </div>
            <figcaption class="info-wrap" style="padding: 30px">
              <h4 class="title">{{product.productName}}</h4>
              <p class="desc"> {{product.description}}</p>
              <div class="price">
                <div> Price:&#x20b9;{{product.price}}</div>
              </div>
              <p class="text-success">Free shipping</p>
              <p>
                <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" style="margin-right:10px" (click)="addToCart(product)"><b>Add to Cart </b></button>  -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" (click)="detailss(product)">
                  <b>View Details & Buy</b>
                </button>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

Product-ListComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from '../product.service'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Product } from '../../partner/Product';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
  open: boolean;
  marginSize: string;
  sideNavPosition: string;
  collapsedHeight: string;

  brand: Product["brand"];
  battery: Product["battery"];
  camera: Product["camera"];
  color: Product["color"];
  //phoneCondition: Product["phoneCondition"];
  ram: Product["ram"];
  resolution: Product["resolution"];
  storage: Product["storage"];

  searchBrand: string = "";
  searchBattery: string = "";
  searchCamera: string = "";
  searchCondition: string = "";
  searchColor: string = "";
  searchRam: string = "";
  searchResolution: string = "";
  searchStorage: string = "";



  constructor(private productService: ProductService, private router: Router) { }
  products: any[];
  prod: Object[];
  ngOnInit() {

    this.marginSize = '0px';
    this.sideNavPosition = "relative";
    this.open = false;``
    this.getProduct();


    this.productService.brandFilter().subscribe(data => {
      this.brand = data;
    });
    this.productService.batteryFilter().subscribe(data => {
      this.battery = data;
    });
    this.productService.cameraFilter().subscribe(data => {
      this.camera = data;
    });
    this.productService.colorFilter().subscribe(data => {
      this.color = data;
    });
    this.productService.resolutionFilter().subscribe(data => {
      this.resolution = data;
    });
    // this.productService.conditionFilter().subscribe(data => {
    //   this.phoneCondition = data;
    // });
    this.productService.ramFilter().subscribe(data => {
      this.ram = data;
    });
    this.productService.storageFilter().subscribe(data => {
      this.storage = data;
    });

  }
  clearFilters() {
    this.setSearchBrand('');
    this.searchBattery = '';
    this.setSearchCamera('');
    this.setSearchCondition('');
    this.setSearchColor('');
    this.searchRam = '';
    this.setSearchResolution('');
    this.searchStorage = '';
  }
  getProduct() {
    this.productService.getProduct().subscribe(
      product => {
        this.products = product.body;
        console.log(product);
      });

  }
  setSearchBrand(name: string) {

    this.searchBrand = name;
    return this.searchBrand;

  }
  setSearchBattery(name: string) {

    this.searchBattery;
    return this.searchBattery;

  }
  setSearchCamera(name: string) {

    this.searchCamera = name;
    return this.searchCamera;

  }
  setSearchCondition(name: string) {

    this.searchCondition = name;
    return this.searchCondition;

  }
  setSearchColor(name: string) {

    this.searchColor = name;
    return this.searchColor;

  }
  setSearchRam(name: string) {

    this.searchRam = name;
    return this.searchRam;

  }
  setSearchResolution(name: string) {

    this.searchResolution = name;
    return this.searchResolution;

  }
  setSearchStorage(name: string) {

    this.searchStorage = name;
    return this.searchStorage;

  }
  viewProducts() {
    this.router.navigate(["/customers/home"])
  }

  detailss(product: any) {
    this.productService.setProductDetails(product);
    console.log(product)
    this.router.navigate(["/customers/details"]);
  }
  details(products) {
    this.router.navigate(["/customers/home"]);
  }

  addToCart(product) {
    this.productService.addToCart(product)
  }

}
```

brand-filter.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'brandFilter'
})
export class BrandFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], searchBrand: string[], searchBattery: string, searchCamera: string, searchColor: string
  ,searchRam: string,searchResolution: string,searchStorage: string ): any[] {
    if (items && items.length){
      return items.filter(item =>{
          if (searchBrand && item.brand.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchBrand) === -1){
              return false;
          }
          if (searchBattery && item.battery.toString().indexOf(searchBattery) === -1){
              return false;
          }
          if (searchCamera && item.camera.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchCamera.toLowerCase()) === -1){
              return false;
          }
          if (searchColor && item.color.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchColor.toLowerCase()) === -1){
            return false;
          }
          // if (searchCondition && item.phoneCondition.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchCondition.toLowerCase()) === -1){
          //   return false;
          // }
          if (searchRam && item.ram.toString().indexOf(searchRam) === -1){
            return false;
          }
          if (searchResolution && item.resolution.indexOf(searchResolution) === -1){
            return false;
          }
          if (searchStorage && item.storage.toString().indexOf(searchStorage) === -1){
            return false;
          }

          return true;
     })
  }
    else{
        return items;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Personally I would drop the whole pipe approach and go with an observable-based approach; wrap your filter properties in a `FormGroup`, redirect your search methods to set the corresponding members of the group and map the group´s value changes into a filtered list of objects.

Comment: agree with Jota, please also read: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: Could you be a little more clear? I have been looking up how to do this without a pipe, and there's no good tutorials or guides

Comment: Please....I need an answer...your advice has gotten me nowhere